# Как установить pywin32 на PyPy?

Tags: python, pip, windows-7, pywin32, pypy

Пытался установить pywin32, выдало ошибку:

```
D:\Download>pypy -m pip install pywin32
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from ver
sions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

Погуглил, нашел pypiwin32, но при установке тоже выдает ошибку:

```
Пробовал также установить так: pypy -m pip install pypiwin32 --pre (ошибка таже)
C:\Windows\system32>pypy -m pip install pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

├Ч python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
тФВ exit code: 1
тХ░тФА> [7 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cupl1f0p\pypiwin32_22
fafcc1eadd4bc780247dab0c362b25\setup.py", line 121
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("B
uilding pywin32", pywin32_version)?
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit
h pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

├Ч Encountered error while generating package metadata.
тХ░тФА> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Попробовал поставить в ручную в виде пакетов .tar.gz и .whl, но нет, опять ошибка:

```
D:\Download>pypy -m pip install pypiwin32-223.tar.gz
Processing d:\download\pypiwin32-223.tar.gz
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (fro
m pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
```

Версия моего pypy:

```
D:\Download>pypy -V
Python 3.8.15 (c20fe3f310f1d209d69a71d903dd17e5c3cf0de9, Dec 05 2022, 15:20:36)
[PyPy 7.3.10 with MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

После первой ошибки сразу обновил pip

```
D:\Download>pypy -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\pypy3.8\pypy3.8-v7.3.10-w
in64\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
```

Пока ничего не помогло, никак не получается поставить pywin32, что я делаю не так? (На обычный python 3.8 поставилось без проблем)

Comment: "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" означает что вы ставите pywin32 для Python 2.7 (там print без скобок) на Python 3.8 (там print со скобками). Это не будет работать. Найдите совместимую версию.

Comment: У меня версия Python 3.8, как такое может быть? Я указал вывод версии pypy

Comment: Почистите кеши. Я указал на противоречие в коде. Как оно возникло - не знаю. Я мог ошибиться, но выглядит так будто версии питонов смешаны.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69482594/failed-to-build-pypiwin32

Comment: `pypiwin32` - устаревший пакет. По ссылке выше говорят что надо понизить версию Питона до 3.9.

Comment: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1588